# Extracting pattern from string with unknown length

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm still in a very embryonic stage in Java and I am trying to figure out how to extract all specific values.

That are in this form (pattern) `[A-H][1-8]` out of a String which length is unknown.
So for example if my string is `" F5 F4 E3 "` I want to assign `F5` to a variable, `F4` to a variable, `E3` to another variable.

Or if my string would be `" A2 "` I would like to assign `A2` to a variable.
I kind of have a feeling that I should use an `Array` to store the values.
Please note that between the wanted pattern there are blank spaces `"blankE2blank"`.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class List {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;
        char[] Wanted = new char[]{?}; // What should I use here?
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s*d+\\s*D+\\s*d+");
        String Motherstring = " F5 F4 E3 "; // this is just an example but the extraction should work for every string
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(Motherstring);
        while (pat.find()) {
            Wanted[i] = pat; // ?
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `String#split` to split the input by space `"\\s+"` and process the resulting array `String[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `\b` anchor. Below is hand-written example, I haven't test it. It just shows the idea.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class List {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;
        char[] Wanted = new char[3];// Instead of array any dynamic collection should be used here. Since I'm not familiar with Java collections enough, Im leaving array here for correct work
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b");
        String Motherstring = " F5 F4 E3 ";
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(Motherstring);
        while (pat.find()) {
            Wanted[i]= pat.group();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million finally figured it out!

Comment: Hope it helps others too !

Comment: Actually, I'm glad that you cared about my comment and gave feedback, so you've already passed the simple filter from every other yelling "omg y u downvotes" so now I can talk to you more about  your code. The intent and flow is clear, but what you didn't realize was that: 1. The fields are not named to Java semantics `camelCasing` 2. The pattern wasn't restrictive enough, and you could simplify the char initialization altogether:

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java enough, also collections are out of scope of this question. Also I fully agree, dynamic colletcions are much better.

Comment: `char[] wanted = new char[motherString.replaceFirst("\\W+").replaceAll("\\w*(\\w)\\W*", "$1").length()]`, which takes unique word character sequences, subtracts everything and leaves one behind, then takes the final length and uses it for the length of the array, which will be just right for what you're doing in `Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b")`.

Comment: Corrected the example

Comment: @Unihedron, from performance point of view calculating count is expensive and I would avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array. Use a `List`. The size is dynamic and allows you to `add` objects. See this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-H][1-8]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" F5 F4 E3 ");

// Create a new list (ArrayList) to store Strings.
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// For every match of the regexp in the test string:
while (matcher.find())
    // Add the match to the list.
    list.add(matcher.group());

System.out.println(list);
```

Here is an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/aOFEj1). The STDOUT prints:

```
[F5, F4, E3]
```

Comment: I agree, dynamic collection is the best here